# Access. How to Create a record and select that record in CBO on another form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two forms `frmProductCreate` and `frmColourCreate`.

In `frmProductCreate` I have:

- Combobox: `colourID`
- Button: `btnColCreate`

The idea is that if a user needs to create a new colour, they can click on the create button which opens `frmColourCreate`, name the new colour and click save button. Which will save the new colour in the colours table (which is the record source for the cbo `ColourID` in `frmProductCreate`). Then requery `colourID` in `frmProductCreate` and close `frmColourCreate`.

What I also want this save button to do is after the requery to select the cbo `colourID` and go to the last created colour. i.e. the last record. I have tried a few codes but failed to make it work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub btnSavecol_Click()
    Dim cancel As Integer

    If Me.ColName = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a Colour Name."
        DoCmd.GoToControl "ColName"

        cancel = True
    Else
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to create new Colour?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            cancel = True
        Else
            CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Colours (ColName) VALUES ('" & Me.ColName & "')"

            Me.ColName = ""

            DoCmd.Close

            If CurrentProject.AllForms("frmProductCreate").IsLoaded = False Then
                cancel = True
            Else
                Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Requery
                'Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.SetFocus
                'Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.items.Count = -1
                'Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Selected(Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Count - 1) = False

                'YourListBox.SetFocus
                'YourListBox.ListIndex = YourListBox.ListCount - 1
                'YourListBox.Selected(YourListBox.ListCount - 1) = False
            End If

            If CurrentProject.AllForms("frmProductDetails").IsLoaded = False Then
                cancel = True
            Else
                Forms!frmproductDetails!ColourID.Requery
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just after `Requery` add following code `Forms!frmproductDetails!ColourID = Me.ColName`

Comment: thank you for your fast reply mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- Whatfor is the variable `cancel`? Because it is not used, I removed it.
- I have no really idea whatfor you need `Me.ColName = ""`.
- Why do you close the current form so early? I moved `DoCmd.Close` to the end.
- I made your code a bit more readable, by removing 'arrow-code' (those nested `IFs`).

Finally try this:

```
Private Sub btnSavecol_Click()
    If Me.ColName.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a Colour Name."
        DoCmd.GoToControl "ColName"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to create new Colour?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Colours (ColName) VALUES ('" & Me.ColName.Value & "')"

    If Not CurrentProject.AllForms("frmProductCreate").IsLoaded Then GoTo Done

    Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Requery

    'This sets the ComboBox 'ColourID' to the new colour:
    'Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Value = Me.ColName.Value

    'If you use an automatic generated ID in the table 'Colours', then you will have to get that ID from the color and set it to the ComboBox:
    Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Value = DLookup("ColID", "Colours", "ColName = '" & Me.ColName.Value & "'")

    Me.ColName.Value = ""

    If Not CurrentProject.AllForms("frmProductDetails").IsLoaded Then GoTo Done

    Forms!frmproductDetails!ColourID.Requery

Done:
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the quick reply. I will give your suggestion a try. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: I am using an Autonumber for the colour ID. the way I created the frmColourCreate form, is the ColName textbox is unbound. So when the SQL statement enters the data to the Colour table, the table generates an Autonumber for ColID. I believe its the "Last" ColID value from the colour table I need to insert into Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Value. am I wrong in thinking so?

Comment: What are the `RowSource` and `Bound Column` of the Combobox `ColourID`?

Comment: ColourID CBO is unbound. For the row source, I created a query from the builder. Selecting ColID and ColourName. In format, I selected 2 columns with 0cm,1cm so only the name shows.

Comment: 'Forms!frmproductCreate!ColourID.Value = DLookup("ID", "Colours", "ColName = '" & Me.ColName.Value & "'")
Maybe I can do DLookup for the last value of the ID in table Colours?

Comment: `Control Source` binds controls to data source. `Bound Column` defines which column will be the 'value' of the combo box. So it seems `ColID` to be the 'value'. That means that you have to set the ID and not the text to the combo box. You need to make a `DLookup` to get the ID by the text, like I described in the code. I reworked my sample code (the DLookup) a bit now by using your fieldnames.

Comment: Looks great. I'll try this tonight. Thank you very much.

Comment: Worked a treat! Mate you are great! Thank you